# Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference to org.apache.spark.Logging encountered in class file 'HBaseContext.class'

Tags: spring, scala, apache-spark, hbase

I'm trying to use HBase with Spark 2.1.0 and Scala 2.11.2.

After attempting to run my Spring application, I get the error:

> Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference to org.apache.spark.Logging
>   encountered in class file 'HBaseContext.class'. Cannot access type
>   Logging in package org.apache.spark. The current classpath may be
>   missing a definition for org.apache.spark.Logging, or
>   HBaseContext.class may have been compiled against a version that's
>   incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.

build.sbt

```
import sbt.ExclusionRule

name := "..."
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

val elasticVersion = "5.4.1"

resolvers += "bintray-spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"

/* Dependencies */
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Framework and configuration
  "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-web" % "1.5.3.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework.cloud" % "spring-cloud-starter-config" % "1.3.1.RELEASE",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-validator" % "5.2.4.Final",

  /* Dependencies */
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.7",

  // Spark
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0",
  "graphframes" % "graphframes" % "0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11",

  //JDBC
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.35",

  // Persistence
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" % elasticVersion,
  "org.mongodb.spark" % "mongo-spark-connector_2.11" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-spark" % "2.0.0-alpha-1"


).map(_.excludeAll(ExclusionRule("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"), ExclusionRule("log4j", "log4j")))


/* Assembly     */
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```